# How to extract numpy arrays from specific column in pandas frame and stack them as a single numpy array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas frame like this.

```
pd.DataFrame(data={'name':['name1','name2'],'vector':[np.array([1,2,3,4]),np.array([12,22,34,4])]})
```

I want to extract the vectors from the frame as a matrix like this.

```
np.array([[1,2,3,4],[12,22,34,4]])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
np.array(df['vector'].tolist())
```

will result in

```
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [12, 22, 34,  4]])
```

or

```
df['vector'].as_matrix()
```

will result in

```
array([array([1, 2, 3, 4]), array([12, 22, 34,  4])], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 2):

`df.vector.values` should be the shortest.